# Read synchronous (i.e. "receive" instead of listener)

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, synchronous

The following code snippet (standalone Java-application) will never find any messages on the queue while the same client, when implemented using message listeners, does (Using Glassfish 3.1):

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("foo.Factory");

partsQueue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("foo.PartsQueue");

conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
consumer = session.createConsumer(partsQueue);

conn.start();

Message msg = null;
int cnt = -1;
do {
    cnt++;
    msg = consumer.receiveNoWait();
} while (msg != null);

        System.out.println("cnt: " + cnt);
```

If I use the following code after creating the consumer, the listener will find the messages and consume them successfully:

```
listener = new AssemblerListener(this);
consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
System.out.println("waiting for msgs...");
conn.start();
```

As mentioned, standalone Java client, I'm not trying to do something in MDBs synchronously. Any ideas? Did not find any hints why synchronous read should not work here. Using message listeners is not the best option in this case as I have to read two messages using different filters sometimes.

Comment: So the first code never stops ? (the while loop)

Comment: It does stop immediatly and outputs 0.

Comment: so you got something from `receiveNoWait` isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: I only got null returned from receiveNoWait() (like there were no messages in the queue). When using the listener, I get all the messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way i receive Meessages:

```
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);

    // Getting JMS connection from the server
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory= activeMQConnectionFactory;

    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

    // Creating session for sending messages
    Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);


    // Getting the queue 'TESTQUEUE'
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("queue_name");

    // MessageConsumer is used for receiving (consuming) messages

    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

    connection.start();        

    // Here we receive the message.
    // By default this call is blocking, which means it will wait
    // for a message to arrive on the queue.
    Message message= consumer.receive(500);
    while(message!= null)
    {

        // There are many types of Message and TextMessage
        // is just one of them. Producer sent us a TextMessage
        // so we must cast to it to get access to its .getText()
        // method.
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) 
        {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
       //     BytesMessage Byte

            System.out.println("Received message '"+ textMessage.getText() + "'");
        }           
        message = consumer.receive(1);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your sample. There've been two problems: Destination instead of ctx.lookup for Queue has been the first, altough I don't really understand why I need a Destination this time but not if I'm using a message listener. receive(500) works, fine, so does receive(50) but receive(5) does not as receiveNoWait() does neither. (I'd call such behaviour "bug" or is there some way this could be useful?)

Comment: I once faced that behaveiour that receiveNoWait() not giving me a message even when there was a message on the queue. That happend for 400+ messages on the queue. I to think this is indeed a "bug" and i think the Apache also recognize this as a bug

Answer (score 0):

`consumer.receiveNoWait()` returns `null` if at the time the queue was emptu.
Your code does not try to receive messages again if it got null.

You should either keep looping or use `consumer.receive()` which will block until a message is available

Comment: The queue is not empty. I've two other pieces of code, one using a QueueBrowser to list the messages, one using a message listener (second code snippet in original question) I run after this version has failed. So, messages are in the queue and can be consumed using a message listener, just not synchronously.

Comment: if you use `receive` instead of `receiveNoWait` it will block forever ?

Comment: Originally, it has not. The problem has been that I did not use Destination as suggested by Michael A. Now it does.